# Symfony 2 When running Generate:Bundle it does not work

Tags: symfony

I am trying to add a new bundle using the console with the follow code...

```
php app/console generate:bundle
```

How ever it is giving me the following error...

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]                    
  Warning: date_default_timezone_get(): It is not safe to rely on the system'  
  s timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or  
   the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those me  
  thods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled th  
  e timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please s  
  et date.timezone to select your timezone. in /Users/Phil/Sites/SoccerTips24  
  /vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php line 233                      



generate:bundle [--namespace="..."] [--dir="..."] [--bundle-name="..."] [--format="..."] [--structure]
```

I understand the first one is something to do with the time settings but then bundles wont add to my src folder... 
Any ideas how to fix?

Answer (score 2):

Set timezone in your php.ini

```
 php -i |grep php.ini
```

uncomment timezone record, and set you timezone:

```
date.timezone = "Europe/Paris"
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you go to your php.ini and set your timezone it should work.